# WPF - How to bind to a Dependency Property of custom class

Tags: data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm once again in WPF binding hell :) I have a public class (`Treatment`) as follows:

```
public class Treatment()  
{  
...    
    public Ticker SoakTimeActual;   
...  
}
```

Within `Ticker` is a Dependency Property:

```
public class Ticker : FrameworkElement
{     
    // Value as string
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayIntervalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayInterval", typeof(string), typeof(Ticker), null);
    public string DisplayInterval
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayIntervalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayIntervalProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

In my app, a single `Treatment` object is created and is meant to be easily accessible in XAML (in `app.xaml` ):

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <u:Treatment
         x:Key="currentTreatment" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, I need to bind to the `DisplayInterval` dependency property of `SoakTimeActual` to display this text in its current state. Here is my attempt, which doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock              
   Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource currentTreatment}, Path=SoakTimeActual.DisplayInterval}"/>
```

This, of course, compiles ok, but will not display anything. I'm assuming I've made a mistake with change notification or `DataContext` or both.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF binding only operates on properties, not fields.

Therefore, you need change your `SoakTimeActual` field to a property, like this:

```
public class Treatment
{  
...    
    public Ticker SoakTimeActual { get; set; }
...  
}
```